# How Model Checking works with User Interaction

Tags: formal-methods, model-checking, testing

In order to understand how to apply Model Checking, I am wondering how to apply it to a pseudo-realistic async program.

Say I have the following pseudocode:

```
var array = []

window.onclick = a

function a() {
  setTimeout(b, 10)
}

function b() {
  setTimeout(c, 100)
}

function c() {
  var data = new Data(1)
  array.push(data)
}

function Data(integer) {
  this.integer = integer
}
```

The program asynchronously does `a() -> b() -> c()` on click and constructs a new `Data` object.

Say I have a specification that says "The program will eventually create a `Data` object on click within 200ms". Wondering what the Model Checker does to prove that this is correct in the program.

So first I rewrite my program as a state machine.

- State `start`

  - Transition to State `idle`.
- State `idle`

  - Transition `click` to State `a`.
- State `a`

  - Transition `setTimeout` to State `b`.
- State `b`

  - Transition `setTimeout` to State `c`.
- State `c`

  - Transition "function" to State `d` (does `var data = new Data(1); array.push(data)`).
- State `d`

  - Transition to State `idle`

Then the model checker starts at the `start` state and needs a "click" event to trigger going to state `a`. Wondering what the model checker path/trace will look like going from start to state `d`. That will help in understanding how to apply model checking. I don't see how to provide the click event to the model checker or how it should prove the Data statement. It seems like there needs to be some sort of testing/input generation going on but not quite sure (like for generating a fake click event for example).

Comment: Unless you run a model checker to completion, which is usually infeasible, a model checker doesn't prove the usual sorts of statements its applied to, e.g. safety statements that say that some invariant always holds. A model checker is not usually used to prove things. It is used like testing. If it finds a counter-model, you have a problem, but if it doesn't then you don't know whether the code is right or not.